# How to mutate new variable equal to existing variable (MA) conditional on third variable (date)

Tags: r, date, group-by, conditional-statements, dplyr

Seems like a straightforward question, but I'm not seeing an answer that works.

I have data which looks a little like:

```
Job     Date      Total     MA30     Month        Monthly_avg
A      2020-01-03   19      8.86     2020-01-01     8.18
A      2020-01-05   3       8.36     2020-01-01     8.18      
A      2020-02-06   4       8.46     2020-02-01     7.54
A      2020-02-11   1       8.16     2020-02-01     7.54
A      2020-03-03   3       6.90     2020-03-01     7.05
A      2020-03-04   5       6.4      2020-03-01     7.05
B
B
B
C
...
```

The code I used up to that point was:

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
  group_by(Job, Date) %>%
  summarise(Total = n()) %>%
  mutate(MA30 = zoo::rollmean(Total, k = 30, fill = NA, align="right")) %>%
  group_by(Month = floor_date(Date, "month")) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(Job, Month) %>%
  mutate(Monthly_avg = mean(MA30, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Now, I would like to add one more line in the code to create a new variable (Index) that equals the `Monthly_avg` when Month = "2020-02-01". I'd like this new variable to be different for each Job type, to create an index value for each Job during the month of Feb.

So the end result would be:

```
Job     Date      Total     MA30     Month        Monthly_avg  Index
A      2020-01-03   19      8.86     2020-01-01     8.18       7.54
A      2020-01-05   3       8.36     2020-01-01     8.18       7.54
A      2020-02-06   4       8.46     2020-02-01     7.54       7.54
A      2020-02-11   1       8.16     2020-02-01     7.54       7.54
A      2020-03-03   3       6.90     2020-03-01     7.05       7.54
A      2020-03-04   5       6.4      2020-03-01     7.05       7.54 
B
B
B
C
...
```

I've tried:

```
%>%
  mutate(index = monthly_avg, which(month == "2020-02-01"))
```

and ifelse does not seem to apply in this scenario, as I want the new variable to be uniform.

Apologies if this is included somewhere else, but I haven't found a solution yet.

Many many thanks for your insight!

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```r
df2 %>% group_by( Job ) %>%
    mutate( Index = first(Monthly_avg[ Month == "2020-02-01" ]) )
```

Used with your data (and some fake data added):

```r
library(magrittr)

df2 <- read.table(text=
"Job     Date      Total     MA30     Month        Monthly_avg
A      2020-01-03   19      8.86     2020-01-01     8.18
A      2020-01-05   3       8.36     2020-01-01     8.18
A      2020-02-06   4       8.46     2020-02-01     7.54
A      2020-02-11   1       8.16     2020-02-01     7.54
A      2020-03-03   3       6.90     2020-03-01     7.05
A      2020-03-04   5       6.4      2020-03-01     7.05
",header=TRUE)


## Some fake data:
set.seed(100)
df2 %<>% rbind(
             df2 %>%
             mutate(
                 Monthly_avg = Monthly_avg*1.1,
                 Job = "B"
             )
         )

## The magic:
df2 %>% group_by( Job ) %>%
    mutate( Index = first(Monthly_avg[ Month == "2020-02-01" ]) )
```

Output:

```
   <chr> <chr>      <int> <dbl> <chr>            <dbl> <dbl>
 1 A     2020-01-03    19  8.86 2020-01-01        8.18  7.54
 2 A     2020-01-05     3  8.36 2020-01-01        8.18  7.54
 3 A     2020-02-06     4  8.46 2020-02-01        7.54  7.54
 4 A     2020-02-11     1  8.16 2020-02-01        7.54  7.54
 5 A     2020-03-03     3  6.9  2020-03-01        7.05  7.54
 6 A     2020-03-04     5  6.4  2020-03-01        7.05  7.54
 7 B     2020-01-03    19  8.86 2020-01-01        9.00  8.29
 8 B     2020-01-05     3  8.36 2020-01-01        9.00  8.29
 9 B     2020-02-06     4  8.46 2020-02-01        8.29  8.29
10 B     2020-02-11     1  8.16 2020-02-01        8.29  8.29
11 B     2020-03-03     3  6.9  2020-03-01        7.76  8.29
12 B     2020-03-04     5  6.4  2020-03-01        7.76  8.29
```

Answer (score 0):

Please include the packages you are using in your code. I guess your code is based on

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(zoo)
```

It would have been easier, if you had included more data especially for another Job Type with your desired output.

So, here we go. Suppose your data looks like this:

```r
df <- read_table2("Job     Date      Total     MA30     Month        Monthly_avg
A      2020-01-03   19      8.86     2020-01-01     8.18
A      2020-01-05   3       8.36     2020-01-01     8.18      
A      2020-02-06   4       8.46     2020-02-01     7.54
A      2020-02-11   1       8.16     2020-02-01     7.54
A      2020-03-03   3       6.90     2020-03-01     7.05
A      2020-03-04   5       6.4      2020-03-01     7.05
B      2020-02-11   1       8.16     2020-02-01     1.25
B      2020-02-11   1       8.16     2020-02-02     9.99")
```

Using `dplyr` and some SQL-style self-joining

```r
df %>%
  group_by(Job) %>%
  filter(Month == "2020-02-01") %>%
  select(Job, Monthly_avg) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  left_join(df, by=c("Job")) %>%
  select(Job, Date, Total, MA30, Month, Monthly_avg=Monthly_avg.y, Index=Monthly_avg.x)
```

returns

```r
# A tibble: 8 x 7
# Groups:   Job [2]
  Job   Date       Total  MA30 Month      Monthly_avg Index
  <chr> <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <date>           <dbl> <dbl>
1 A     2020-01-03    19  8.86 2020-01-01        8.18  7.54
2 A     2020-01-05     3  8.36 2020-01-01        8.18  7.54
3 A     2020-02-06     4  8.46 2020-02-01        7.54  7.54
4 A     2020-02-11     1  8.16 2020-02-01        7.54  7.54
5 A     2020-03-03     3  6.9  2020-03-01        7.05  7.54
6 A     2020-03-04     5  6.4  2020-03-01        7.05  7.54
7 B     2020-02-11     1  8.16 2020-02-01        1.25  1.25
8 B     2020-02-11     1  8.16 2020-02-02        9.99  1.25
```